# MVC Unable to find View in ActionMethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Just started with MVC and I have a problem.
Below is the hierarchy of my files:

```
1.WebJltNZ\JWebJltNZ.Presentation.Web.Mvc\Controllers : LbpProfessionalController
2.WebJltNZ.Presentation.Web.Mvc\ViewModels : LbpProfessional
3.WebJltNZ.Presentation.Web.Mvc\Views\Home\RiskAndInsuranceServices\JltAffinityPartnerships            :LbpProfessionalProtectionApplication
```

The method below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(); // it's cannot be found.
}
```

is unable to find the view.

Am I missing something here. Please help.

Comment: The view should be at `/Views/LbpProfessional/Index.cshtml`. Is it there?

Comment: No it's not there.. its under WebJltNZ.Presentation.Web.Mvc\Views\Home\RiskAndInsuranceServices\JltAffinityPartnerships\LbpProfessionalProtectionApplication.cshtml.. is this the prob?

Comment: Yes. That is your "prob" right there. MVC is working by convention - it cannot "know" where your view is otherwise: you need to use the convention, or specify the path to your view.

Comment: It has to be where @Kobi told you, or else you have to pass the view's location to View():  `return View("~/Views/Home/RiskAndInsuranceServices/JltAffinityPartnerships/LbpProfessionalProtectionApplication");`   I've had some cases with templates where adding folders past the controller resulted in the view engine not finding them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the names wrong. The way it works is that the controller name matches a subfolder inside the view folder; and the action method matches a file inside that subfolder.

This means that the `LbpProfessionalController` in the Controllers folder should match a folder named `LbpProfessional` inside the `Views` folder.

And the `Index` method inside the `LbpProfessionalController` should match a `Index.cshtml` file inside the `\Views\LbpProfessional` folder.

The structure would then look like this

```
\Controllers\LbpProfessionalController.cs
\Views\LbpProfessional\Index.cshtml
```

Note that the name of the controller ends with `...Controller` but the folder name doesn't get that part.

This is the standard way of linking Controllers and Views, and when you follow these rules you can use an action method as simple as this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   // This view will be found if you have given the view the right name 
   // ("Index.cshtml") and put it in the right place (folder named 
   // after controller).
   return View(); 
}
```

But if you want to have a view that differs from the default way of linking then you need to specify the path to that other view. It could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("anotherViewName"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ohlin.. it really helped me and solved the issue.. also your info was too good for a newbie like me.. happy blogging :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. If you're happy with the answer then please also mark my answer as correct. Good luck with all your future MVC adventures :)

Comment: On the left hand side of my answer you can vote up or down if you like the answer. Under this voting section there is a v-shaped figure you can click on for the answer that you consider to be best (if many people have given answers to your question). That figure will then become green, indicating it's your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit Controller class to the class in which you have placed public ActionResult Index()